# How Does User Identification Work In Dialogflow Fulfillment Webhooks?

Tags: dialogflow-es

Let's say I have a desktop app that listens to a user, and leverages Dialogflow to determine intent.

In the app, we just call:
  https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/my-project-name/agent/sessions/123456789:detectIntent

Let's also say the active user is "UserX" in our system, and we need to retrieve information specific to the account.

I understand that Dialogflow utilizes webhooks for fulfillment as described here:
https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment/how-it-works

However, I'm unclear how user information can be sent to our webhook such that we'll be able to tell that "UserX" was the one who made the call to Dialogflow.

Can anyone explain if/how communication of user information is supported in fulfillment webhooks?

Comment: This the question i stuck with currently. Facebook bots have $username parameter, so any user who initiates a chat can be identified as values will be stored as $userid, $username but dialogflow wondering how can this part is not available?

Answer (score 0):

It is supported by fulfillment. There are a number of ways you can do it. Assuming that the user has communicated with the agent, the agent can then store the users response i.e. lets assume the agent asked the user what their name is. Since the agent can store that info (UserX) in a parameter, that parameter can then be passed to the fulfilment. The agent can also store user responses in context parameters and they can also be passed to the fulfilment. Finally even if the user does not provide info to the agent you can also use the dialog flow API to pass data to the agent which in turn can be passed to the fulfillment.

Comment: /Finally even if the user does not provide info to the agent you can also use the dialog flow API to pass data to the agent which in turn can be passed to the fulfillment./ If user didnt provide information, how dialogflow API knows which user?